# Conditionional Perl hash

Tags: perl

i have a Perl hash and want to write inside the hash a conditional variable ? hwo i can do something like this ?

```
my $hash = {
    a => 1,
    if ($flag ==1) {
        b => 2,
    }
    else {
        b => 3,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the conditional expression:

```
my $foo = {
  a => 1,
  b => ($flag == 1) ? 2 : 3
}
```

Note that the conditional is evaluated when you first define `$foo`. If you subsequently change the value of `$flag`, the value of `$foo->{b}` won't change.

Comment: Also note that `$hash` is a bad name, as it's in fact *a hash reference*, so the value is `$hash->{b}`. To use `$hash{b}`, you need to declare `my %hash = ( ... )`.

Comment: Unless the hash value must adopt different values at *run time*, when the value should be callable, perhaps *tied?*

Comment: I think `$hashref` is no better than `$hash`, and it is longer. The `$` indicates that this is a scalar, and so `$hash` must be a reference. But I object to anything being called `@array`, `%hash`, or `$scalar` as identifiers should be about *purpose* rather than *mechanism*. Funnily enough we never see `$scalar`; I wonder why not?

Comment: How about I call it `$foo`, so people can stop reading so much into what just needs to be a syntactically correct placeholder?

Comment: @chepner: Why assign to a variable at all?

Comment: Because the OP had a variable. Really, is this important enough to fixate on?